# как обработать свайп?

Tags: android

Итак в чем заключается вопрос: мне нужно сделать, что когда пользователь делает свайп пальцем, выполняется какое-то действие, например всплывает сообщение или открывается новое activity.
P.s Не кидайте ссылки на иностранные сайты Объясните как это сделать или Киньте простой исходник

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вот такой пример для вас:

### MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GestureDetectorCompat lSwipeDetector;

RelativeLayout main_layout;
TextView tvTxt;
int i;

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 130;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_DISTANCE = 300;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    i = 1;
    lSwipeDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
    main_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    tvTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTxt);
    tvTxt.setText("" + i);

    main_layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return lSwipeDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}

private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_DISTANCE)
            return false;
        if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) {
            i++;
            tvTxt.setText("" + i);
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Number"
    android:id="@+id/tvTxt"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

leftSwipe (слева - направо) будет увеличивать значение TextView на 1 и сразу показывать.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
// This example shows an Activity, but you would use the same approach if
// you were subclassing a View.
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;      
        default : 
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }      
}
```

Comment: swipe и touch это разные вещи.
Различия в том что swipe это жест, и главное его отличие это взаимодействия между несколькими MotionEvent, что чаще всего используется для ограничения расстояния и конечно скорость.
Если onTouch имитировать это, то остаются ряд ситуаций к примеру - когда вы листаете список медленно и ведете пальцем по диагонали(это очень часто) вы будете смещаться по Y тоже на N кол-во пикселей и onTouch сработает и это будет очень не красиво, для этого уже очень давно существует класс GestureDetector. Ещё большой плюс... сейчас напишу ответ... символов нет уже)