# Android перемещение ImageView по swipe

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, swipe

Всем привет!

Реализовано простое активити с картинкой (скрин ниже).

Как сделать выход из активити наподобие как реализовано в приложении VK и во многих других приложениях (свайп вверх/вниз по ImageView). Чтобы при свайпе картинка немного приподнималась/приопускалась в зависимости от свайпа.

При свайпе на определенный модуль высоты активити закрывается, иначе картинка возвращается на начальное положение.

[В принципе обработку свайпа вроде есть понимание как сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489780/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF), но вот как поднимать/опускать ImageView при этом вслед за пальцем на экране, что то я не догоняю. Возможно не в ту сторону иду, направьте в нужное русло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:transitionName="@string/shared_image"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На счет перемещения за пальцем - добавляешь к своему ImageView onTouchListener:

```
ImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    view.animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                            .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();                     
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Таки образом у тебя ImageView будет следовать за пальцем. А дальше, когда ты отпустишь ее (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) определяешь - если смещение не большое, то с анимацией перемещаешь ImageView обратно, если смещение достаточное - то выходишь из активити.

Comment: Как раз то что нужно! Спасибо, странно что сам не дошел до этого, видимо время далеко за полночь повлияло :)